# How to calculate sum of dynamically row adding table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table,it can add dynamical rows.what i'm trying to do is,calculate `amount` column sum and display in `Expences` field.then reduce expencess from income and display total in balance field

eg:
when user fill first row with `book` and price for book in `amount` column.then click `add item` button and add another row.that time calculate sum of book and pen and display in `expences` field.total will display `balance` field.

```
 <div class="col-xs-12">Income (Rs) : <input type="number" min="0.01" step="0.01" name="income" value="2536.67" id="income" >
            </div> 
            <div class="col-xs-12">Expences (Rs) : <input type="number" min="0.01" step="0.01" name="expence" value="" readonly id="expence">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12">Balance (Rs) : <input type="number" min="0.01" step="0.01" name="balance" value="" readonly id="balance">
            </div> 

<table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">
                <thead>
                    <tr >
                        <th class="text-center">
                            #
                        </th>
                        <th class="text-center">
                            Category
                        </th>
                        <th class="text-center">
                            Item Name
                        </th>
                        <th class="text-center">
                            Amount
                        </th>
                        <th class="text-center">

                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr id='addr0'>
                        <td>
                        1
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <select class="form-control" name="cat">
                            <option value="bill">Bill</option>
                            <option value="exchange">Exchange</option>

                        </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <input type="text" name='name0'  placeholder='Item Name' class="form-control"/>
                        </td>
                        <td class='amount'>
                        <input type="number" name='amount' placeholder='Amount' class="form-control" id='amount'/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="file" class="form-control" name="upload" />

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id='addr1'></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

    <a id="add_row" class="btn btn-default pull-left">Add Item</a><a id='delete_row' class="pull-right btn btn-default">Delete Item</a>

    <button type="Submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right btn-lg" >Submit</button>
```

Add,delete row query

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
      var i=1;
     $("#add_row").click(function(){
      $('#addr'+i).html("<td>"+ (i+1) +"</td><td><select class='form-control' name='cat"+i+"'><option value='bill'>Bill</option><option value='exchange'>Exchange</option></select><td><input name='name"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='Item Name' class='form-control input-md'  /> </td><td class='amount'><input  name='mail"+i+"' type='number' min='0.01' step='0.01' placeholder='Amount' id='amount"+i+"'  class='form-control input-md'></td><td><input type='file' name='upload"+i+"' class='form-control'/></td>");

      $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr'+(i+1)+'"></tr>');
      i++; 
  });
     $("#delete_row").click(function(){
         if(i>1){
         $("#addr"+(i-1)).html('');
         i--;
         }
     });

});

</script>
```

i tried this query.this is cal from table td class.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.amount').each(function() {
    calculateSum();
});
});

 function calculateSum() {

var sum = 0;

    $(".amount").each(function() {

        //add only if the value is number
        if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
        }

    });
$('#expence').text(sum);    
};
```

[image]

Comment: do not forget to accept and upvote the answer, which helps.

Answer (score 1):

This might be because, your function `calculateSum();` isn't triggering. You can probably use `.change` to check, if any value changed for this class and then calculate the sum.

```
$( ".amount" ).change(function (){
var sum=0;
$('.amount').each(function(i, obj){


 if($.isNumeric(this.value)) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
        }

 })
 $('#expence').val(sum);
 });
```

**[>>Demo<<](https://jsfiddle.net/10818fbo/3/)**

Comment: Yes, I believe this is it! You can further simplify your `!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0` by `$.isNumeric(this.value)` since you clearly *are* using jquery.

Comment: @Ravi, This does not work for dynamically added amount rows, the tag "amount" is name in his code. not class used in your example.

Comment: @RamakanthPutta `amount` is not a tag, that is a class. As per his existing js code

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code, it will work for dynamic elements too, just ensure that they have `class` name `amount`:

```js
$(".amount").on('change', calculate);

function calculate() {
  var sum = 0;
  $('.amount').each(function(i, obj) {
    if ($.isNumeric(this.value)) {
      sum += parseFloat(this.value);
    }
  });
  $('#expense').val(sum);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Amount : <input type="text" class="amount"><br/> Amount : <input type="text" class="amount"><br/> Amount : <input type="text" class="amount"><br/> Expense : <input type="text" id="expense">
```